# Trying to understand a Gulp build error - Emitting error involving zlib.js & Gzip

Tags: node.js, gulp

Has anyone seen this error? I cannot understand the origin of the error. Searching for an answer has been fruitless. To give some context, I was merging changes from another branch via SVN, which probably mangled the merge, but I still can't figure out what went wrong within the logic. Thanks in advance.

```
zlib.js:166
 callback(null, buf);
 ^
TypeError: object is not a function
 at Gzip.onEnd (zlib.js:166:5)
 at Gzip.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
 at _stream_readable.js:910:16
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: you are probably trying to compress something and the callback given to the compressor in your code (or in gulp code) is undefined or is not a function

Comment: Thanks for your response, @JeromeWAGNER. Interestingly, this is a dev build process, so I'm not actually compressing or minifying any logic if that's what you mean. Sorry, I'm not well-versed in Node.js yet, so please pardon my lack of knowledge.

Comment: well 'zlib' is a compression library so your build process is probably trying to zip or unzip something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out by just commenting out some logic. Unfortunately, it was a conflict with the `gulp-size` module. I was passing in the an object as an argument to `gulp-size` as the following `{ showFiles: true, gzip: true}`. I don't know why it was causing issues *now* considering I had no conflicts running this module in my Gulp task in the past. Thanks again, @JeromeWAGNER.